# Please help in finding the error

Tags: c++, netbeans

I did a program on NetBeans, but there is an error that I have and I do not know how to do it.
If anyone of you could help me that would be great.

Here are the questions I need to answer:

Write, as cleanly as possible a C ++ program that:

1) Declares an array classique1
t1 strings ("to C") containing the
names of the days of the week (Monday, Tuesday, ...)

2) Establish, from t1, t2 a new classic table containing also the names
days of the week, but sorted in ascending alphabetical order

3) Displays at the rate of one per line day name, the content of tables t1 and t2

4) Remove the table t2

5) Ends

And in this LINK : http://www.codeshare.io/wGWlQ    is the program I did.

Comment: Just technical note: you should include the code directly to question (not external links) and create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so the code is not too large

Comment: Please report the relevant code here, and narrow down your problem, no one will give the overall solution of your homework

Comment: put your code in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the "as cleanly as possible a C++ program":

```
std::array<std::string, 7> t1 = { // Array of strings t1
   "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
   "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"
};

auto t2 = t1; // Create t2
std::sort(std::begin(t2), std::end(t2)); // to sort the right order

std::cout << "t1 content: " << std::endl; // Display contents
for (const auto& x : t1) {
   std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

std::cout << "t2 content: " << std::endl; // Display contents
for (const auto& x : t2) {
   std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

// Remove the table t2
// Ends
```

If you really have to use c-strings you can just change the type of the array to `const char*`?

Comment: You'll need something like  `const char* t1[8]` and a nullptr at `t1[7]` per convention or pass around its size for the C string case.

Comment: thank you all for your help i appreciate it @FlorisVelleman and rubenvb